# Javascript table inside table not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a table inside a table so I can organize stuff in the right place. But I simple cannot set the table width. Here is a picture of the table

[image]

and circled in red is the table inside table that I've created, it has one row 3 columns:

[image]

and here is the code I've used to create the 2nd table:

```
// attack type
    var farmTableAttack = dom.cn("table");

    var ftableBodyAttack = dom.cn("tbody");

    farmTableAttack.style.tableLayout = "fixed";

    farmTableAttack.width = "20px";

    ftableBodyAttack.setAttribute("colspan", 4);

    ftableBodyAttack.setAttribute("width", 50);

    tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableCol = dom.cn("th");

    tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 2);

    tableCol.innerHTML = "Attack: ";

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    tableCol = dom.cn("th");

    tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 1);

    tableCol.innerHTML = "N";

    var Button = createInputButton("checkbox");

    Button.id = "attackTypeN";

        Button.checked = GM_getValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela") == "normal";

        Button.addEventListener("click", function() {

            if (Button.checked) {
                Button.checked = false;
                GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela");
            }
            else if (document.getElementbyId("attackTypeA").checked == true) {
                document.getElementbyId("attackTypeA").checked = false;
                GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "normal");
            }

                }, false);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);


    tableCol = dom.cn("th");

    tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 1);

    tableCol.innerHTML = "A";

    var Button = createInputButton("checkbox");


        Button.id = "attackTypeA";

        Button.checked = GM_getValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela") == "assalto";

        Button.addEventListener("click", function() {

            if (Button.checked) {
                Button.checked = false;
                GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela");
            }
            else if (document.getElementbyId("attackTypeN").checked == true) {
                document.getElementbyId("attackTypeN").checked = false;
                GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "assalto");
            }

                }, false);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //append the row in the table
    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    ftableBodyAttack.appendChild(tableRow);

    farmTableAttack.appendChild(ftableBodyAttack);
```

I want the second table to be inside this place (this is the original table without the 2nd table coded into it):

[image]

I simple don't know what to do.

another option would be to fix the stuff inside that circle region of the original table without having to use another table, I just don´t know how to do that.

dom.cn:

```
var dom = new DOMUtils();

//DOM functions

function DOMUtils(doc, ctxt, html) { // from FranMod

    this.cn = function(tag, html) {

        var elem = this.document.createElement(tag);

        if (html)

            elem.innerHTML = html;

        return elem;

    }



    this.ct = function(text) {

        return this.document.createTextNode(text);

    }



    this.id = function(id) {

        return this.document.getElementById(id);

    }



    this.tag = function(tag) {

        return this.document.getElementsByTagName(tag);

    }



    this.xs = function(xpath) {

        var res = this.document.evaluate(xpath, this.context, null,

                XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

        return res.singleNodeValue;

    }



    this.xa = function(xpath) {

        var arr = [];

        var xpr = this.document.evaluate(xpath, this.context, null,

                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

        for (var i = 0; item = xpr.snapshotItem(i); i++)

            arr.push(item);

        return arr.length == 0 ? null : arr;

    }



    this.xo = function(xpath) {

        var ret = this.document.evaluate(xpath, this.context, null,

                XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

        return ret; //no snapshot

    }

    this.find = function(xpath, xpres, doc) {

        if (!doc)

            doc = document;

        else if (typeof doc == 'string')

            doc = cn('div', doc);

        var ret = document.evaluate(xpath, doc, null, xpres, null);



        return xpres == XPFirst ? ret.singleNodeValue : ret;

    }

    this.get = function(id, doc) {

        if (!doc)

            doc = document;

        return doc.getElementById(id);

    }

    if (!doc)

        doc = document;

    if (!ctxt)

        ctxt = doc;

    if (html) {

        this.document = doc.implementation.createDocument('', '', null);

        this.context = doc.createElement('div');

        this.context.innerHTML = html;

        ansDoc.appendChild(this.context);

    } else {

        this.document = doc;

        this.context = ctxt;

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the `dom` object? what is the `cn` function? what is `GM_getValue` etc... Your question leaves too little information available to be used to solve any problem.

Comment: I have add the DOM code to answer your question, GM_getValue is just a greasemonkey function to save and read variables to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if all fails take the three items. put the cell to display block.
put each item into a div with css float: left; works for me ...

Comment: can you please explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If that subtable will only ever be one row, consider NOT using a subtable and instead adding additional cells in that row. For other rows, use `colspan` to span all of those former subtable cells:

```
<table>
  <tr><td colspan='3'>Cell 1</td>                               <td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan='3'>Cell 2</td>                               <td>0</td></tr>

  <tr><td>'subcell'a</td><td>'subcell'b</td><td>'subcell'c</td> <td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

following helle suggestion I used css float left and it solved the problem. here is the final code:

```
Button = dom.cn("div");

Button.setAttribute("style", "width:10px;float:left;");

Button.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

tableCol.appendChild(Button);


Button = dom.cn("div");

Button.setAttribute("style", "float:left;");

Button.innerHTML = "Attack type: ";

tableCol.appendChild(Button);

var Button = createInputButton("checkbox");

Button.id = "attackTypeN";

    Button.checked = GM_getValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela") == "normal";

    Button.addEventListener("click", function() {

        if (Button.checked) {
            Button.checked = false;
            GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela");
        }
        else if (document.getElementbyId("attackTypeA").checked == true) {
            document.getElementbyId("attackTypeA").checked = false;
            GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "normal");
        }

            }, false);

Button.setAttribute("style", "float:left;");

tableCol.appendChild(Button);

Button = dom.cn("div");

Button.setAttribute("style", "float:left;");

Button.innerHTML = "N";

tableCol.appendChild(Button);

var Button = createInputButton("checkbox");


    Button.id = "attackTypeA";

    Button.checked = GM_getValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela") == "assalto";

    Button.addEventListener("click", function() {

        if (Button.checked) {
            Button.checked = false;
            GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "tabela");
        }
        else if (document.getElementbyId("attackTypeN").checked == true) {
            document.getElementbyId("attackTypeN").checked = false;
            GM_setValue("checkBoxAttackType_"+suffixLocal, "assalto");
        }

            }, false);

Button.setAttribute("style", "float:left;");

tableCol.appendChild(Button);

Button = dom.cn("div");

Button.setAttribute("style", "float:left;");

Button.innerHTML = "A";

tableCol.appendChild(Button);

//append the row in the table
tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);
```